# Define CSS selector with pattern

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have following elements:

```
<div class="grid">
   <div class="col-1">First Col</div>
   <div class="col-center-2">Second Col</div>
   <div class="col-center-3">third Col</div>
   <div class="col-3">third Col</div>
</div>
```

i want to add class for all elements which have `"-center-"` word on that. how i can define this selector?

Comment: You might find this article about attribute selectors handy: https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `[attr*=value]` attribute selector

```css
div[class*="-center-"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-1">First Col</div>
  <div class="col-center-2">Second Col</div>
  <div class="col-center-3">third Col</div>
  <div class="col-3">third Col</div>
</div>
```